# Category is being archived in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a couple of pages listed on my website and listed categories for one page(Resources). If I navigate to that resource page and try to access categories it works fine. However, if I am on the home page or any other page and try to navigate to that ant of these category shown below, it show archive on the title page.
Instead what I want is that whenever user tries to access category outside of resource page, it should redirect to the resource page instead of that category.

[image]

Comment: If it's the same menu, the links will be the same no matter which page you're on.  You can check the menu links from Appearance > Customize > Menus

Additionally, WordPress "categories" are the same across the entire site.  Each category has an auto-generated archive page.  The design of the archive page is based on one of the files in your theme (probably archive.php or category.php).